# Running batch file as admin does not echo variable to .txt file nor set the variable to the .txt file's content anymore

Tags: variables, batch-file, echo, admin

I want to run a batch file as admin and echo a variable to a .txt file or if the .txt file exists set a variable to the .txt file's content.

Running the batch file as without admin privileges my code works perfect. When running the batch file as admin my code does not work anymore and the .txt file does not get created nor does the variable get set to the .txt file's content.

Here's my code for echoing to a .txt file and setting a variable to a .txt file's content:

```
:: setting variable to path.txt's content

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%cd%\_temp\path.txt") do if exist "%%a" (
    set "test=%%a"
    goto menu
) else (
    if exist "%cd%\_temp\*" del /f /q "%cd%\_temp\*"
    goto setup
)

:: echoing path

>"%cd%\_temp\path.txt" echo %test%
```

For this code it returns the error `The system cannot find the path specified.` when I run the batch as admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your issue is that the default folder path when running as admin is different to when you run it as yourself.

You can see a discussion of the effect here https://superuser.com/questions/1653018/how-do-i-change-the-default-command-prompt-directory-in-windows-7 for example, but by default the path you'll end up in when starting `cmd.exe` normally vs administrator is different.

You can confirm that by simply adding a `echo %cd%` to your script to display what the current path is.

The simplest option is to specify the full path to your required file, or use a `cd` command to move there at the beginning, that way you're not relying on the default path always being the same. And I'd argue that's just generally good practice in any case.

Comment: When 'Run as administrator' the current directory, (result of `%cd%`), will be ```C:\Windows\System32```.

Comment: @Keith Langmead @Compo thank you for the explanation! That was my problem and I fixed it by adding `cd /d "%~dp0%"` to my script.

Comment: @leiseg, it should technically be ```CD /D "%~dp0"```, note the lack of a trailing percent characteri

Comment: @Compo oh yeah, I added the 2nd `%` by accident.